# [FFmpeg on Windows]: help me converting a set of .png files to a video file

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi everybody I am on windows 10, I installed FFMpeg and I would like to use it to convert 100 .png image files into a video file.

I am using it via the prompt, which is the Windows console, and I am struggling with the syntax (which probability comes from Linux). I set the folder in which ffmpeg.exe is contained as a windows system path as suggested on many websites and I moved the prompt to the folders in which the image files are contained which is reported here:

```
cd C:\video\pnts + ag 40 nm- during-tmpyp 10-12- laser power 7mw- kinetic100- exposure time 1s- gain
```

I would like to convert the image files contained in this folder into a video file, the names of those image files are reported here:

pnts + ag 40 nm- during-tmpyp 10-12- laser power 7mw- kinetic100- exposure time 1s- gain 20 001.png

pnts + ag 40 nm- during-tmpyp 10-12- laser power 7mw- kinetic100- exposure time 1s- gain 20 002.png

...

...

pnts + ag 40 nm- during-tmpyp 10-12- laser power 7mw- kinetic100- exposure time 1s- gain 20 100.png

The number of frames per second whould be 2.

I read on internet that I should have to type something like this

```
ffmpeg -i image-%03d.png video.webm
```

But it looks like there are a lot of variables to consider and all the times I try to set them and run FFmpeg I get an error from the prompt. 
Is there anyone who could suggest me the proper syntax, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use

```
ffmpeg -framerate 2 -i "pnts + ag 40 nm- during-tmpyp 10-12- laser power 7mw- kinetic100- exposure time 1s- gain 20 %03d.png" video.webm
```

I would recommend setting a standard output playback rate, like 24 fps. So,

```
ffmpeg -framerate 2 -i "pnts + ag 40 nm- during-tmpyp 10-12- laser power 7mw- kinetic100- exposure time 1s- gain 20 %03d.png" -r 24 video.webm
```

(this won't speed up the video).